# React form validation min and max and reversible

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how I can make a form validation where there is a min and max value but it can also be reversed. Let me explain.

The JSON data is like this:

```
{
 "limits": {
   "minValue": "160",
   "maxValue": "230",
   "reversible": "true"
 }
}
```

So when reversible is true it is allowed to enter a maxValue of 160 but than the minValue needs to higher than 230. Or the other way around, maxValue 230 minValue 160.

The form is to inter the width and the height of a certain product so that is way you values can be reversible.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do `minValue` and `maxValue` mean in your program? According to your description the `reversible` option set to true would mean that you can have any value.

Comment: minValue and maxValue are the maximum/minimum number you can enter for that input field. So you have 2 input fields, Width and Height. Both have maxValues and minValues.

Comment: And if reversible is true, then you expect values that aren't between the minValue and maxValue?

Comment: If reversible is true than it can be either width: max 160 and height: max 230 or width: max 230 and height: max 160. So it can never be 230x230 or 160x160